# Can Storage Spaces cause Fraps to stutter?

Tags: windows-8, recording, storage-spaces, fraps

So I am using Storage Spaces to get multiple hard drives together under one Drive Letter (regular hard drives). I installed Fraps on it. My OS and my games are installed on another hard drive (an SSD).

When recording with fraps, every 30 seconds or so I have a small stutter. This happens in every game, **no matter what the graphical settings**! Is the Storage Spaces the cause of this? Because Fraps is writing the file to one hard drive but then suddenly decides to swith to another hard drive (because it can, since it's the same letter!)

Comment: Are your files splitting every 4 GB? Every split can cause a noticable lag even when using an SSD. See if the problem persists after disabling that option if it's on

Comment: No, I disabled that option!

Comment: I'm guessing that very few people right now have first-hand experience that would apply here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer the question would be for you to add an additional hard drive that is not part of storage spaces and try recording it to that. If you could record in tandem to both the storage spaces drive letter and the sole drive that would be best. Your hypothesis is definitely plausible, but that appears to be the best way to get a rigorous answer, as opposed to people like me just speculating.